# Node border on Sigma.js

Tags: reactjs, sigma.js

I am working on a React-Sigma.js project that aims to draw a collaboration network. I want to add a border to all nodes in the graph. I am using the following code:

```
nodes.forEach((node) => {
      graph.addNode(node.id, {
        nodeType: "author",
        label: node.name,
        size: 5,   
        topic: node.topic,
        type: "border",
        color: chroma.scale(['#fff',node.topic.color])(node.topic.gamma*3).hex()
      })
    })
```

However, when I run my proj, I encounter this error:

```
sigma.js:787 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'process')
at Sigma.process (sigma.js:787:1)
at Sigma._refresh (sigma.js:874:1)
at Sigma.refresh (sigma.js:1438:1)
at useLoadGraph.js:20:1
at TopicNetwork.tsx:65:1
at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23308:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3919:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3968:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4028:1)
at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23390:1)
```

How can I go on with this?

Comment: can you share the code of TopicNetwork ?